# Retrieving the logged in user in a Mongoose middleware

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm getting my feet wet with Node/Express/Mongoose, and I'm looking for the best strategy to solve the following problem (I tried Googling and searching github):

**I'd like to automatically add a `user_id` field in the mongo document each time a user creates a document.**

**(1)** I wrote an Express auth middleware to handle authentication (using firebase authentication) and adds user data in the request

```
firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
.then(function(decodedToken) {
    req.user = {
        uid: decodedToken.uid,
        email: decodedToken.email
    }
    next();
```

**(2)** A post request/controller retrieves the document data

```
router.post('/api/documents', (req,res) => {
    const document = new Document(req.body);
    document.save((err,doc) => {
    ...
```

**(3)** The document schema has a `pre save` middleware, to add the current user id before saving

```
documentSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    const document = this;
    document.user_id = /// HOW CAN I ACCESS THE CURRENT USER??
    next();
})
```

I obviously I cannot access the original request (tried looking for it when debugging)
[image]

So that leaves me with these options :

- The controller adds the user in the document before passing it to Mongoose <= Cons: I want to add the `user_id` for all future create object requests. Hence a general middleware to DRY.
- The Express auth middleware puts the current user in a global variable which is then accessed by the mongoose middleware <= Cons : I don't like the global variable approach and risk having undesirable side effects. I'm also too new to Node for this solution and need some guidance how to approach that.
- Use firebase-admin to retrieve the current user <= I couldn't find the method in the firebase SDK

Could you guide me to a strategy? Thank you!

Comment: I searched more about this problem, and I came across Continuation Local Storage. Reading blogs, I got the feeling that this feature is not mature and lacks consensus from the community. Maybe Node is not meant to have a Thread context? I don't know. In the mean time, to solve my problem, I decided to pass manually the user to Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone viewing this, you can use `AsyncLocalStorage`

```js
// in an express middleware
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from "async_hooks";
import { NextFunction, Response } from "express";

export const context = new AsyncLocalStorage();

export function middleware(req, _res, next) {
  const user = req.user;

  if (!user) {
    return next();
  }

  context.run(new Map(), () => {
    store.set("userId", user.id);
    next();
  });
}
```

```
// In a mongoose middleware
import {context} from "middleware.js"

// Schema declaration somewhere here

schema.pre("save", function(this) {
  const userId = context.getStore()?.get("userId");
  this.userId = userId
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet of code you shared verifies that the ID token is valid, and decodes the information in it. This token is not automatically passed in with requests from Firebase to your custom Express API, so you'll have to pass it along yourself from your client-side code when you make a request. When the Firebase clients are in a similar situation they pass the token in the `Authentication` header as a `bearer` token.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) specifically the section on [retrieving the ID token on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).

Comment: Yes, this is what this code snippet does :) My question, is how do you pass it to the Mongoose middleware